# Rigify Mesh twisting weird at elbow of arm

Tags: mesh, rigify

I'm using Rigify to make my character poses and animations.

But I have this issue.

For some reason when ever I pull my forearm over my upper arm.
It begins twisting from the point where my characters elbow should be. Why is it doing this?

It's totally fine until I pull it over my upper arm. Kind of annoying.

Here's a picture of how it looks messed up.

[image]

But I also noticed that when ever I move my Elbow IK it tends to rotate my mesh a bit.
So I'm getting the idea that it has something to do with rotating but I don't know how to come about it.

Here's how it looks with me moving the Elbow IK + A closer screen shot.
I also noticed that only my arm's bone connected to the Elbow point is moving. Hmm. Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you move the arm, you have to also move the elbow IK bone. The elbow IK works to compensate for the twisting that happens from the IK movements you make. This takes some getting used to. I had to work for some time on my elbow IKs before I felt I had a decent understanding of them and I still am not 100% on it.

Comment: Wow dude you answered quickly. Thanks a lot that was cool.

But I don't exactly know how to do this. I went into edit mode and I made the elbow forearm parent to my Elbow while keeping off set but that didn't do much of anything.

Comment: It took me some time to get used to the elbow IKs. Sometimes you have to move them in counter-intuitive ways, and sometimes in odd places that don't make sense. In the animation, you'll see them moving all over the place. I think of cases where the the elbowIK is way down on the negative z axis, or inside the character's ribcage. There may be other ways to handle this, and maybe others will have suggestions, but I know from my own experience that I never expected those elbow IKs to function as weirdly as they do. Give yourself room to do some crazy things with them and good luck :)